# Why observable source does not emit values when used in race (or merge) but emits when I manually subscribe to it

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have three observable sources in my code that emit values of the same type.

```
    const setTitle$ = params$.do(
        params => this.titleService.setTitle( `${params[1].appname} - ${this.pagename}` )
    ).switchMap(
        () => Observable.of(true)
    );

    const openDocument$ = params$.switchMap(
        params => this.openDocument(params[0].id)
    );

    const saveDocument$ = params$.switchMap(
        params => this.saveDocument(params[0].id)
    );
```

When i use them in race like this

```
setTitle$.race(
    openDocument$,
    saveDocument$
).subscribe();
```

works only setTitle and when i subscribe manually to another two sorces like

```
const openDocument$ = params$.switchMap(
    params => this.openDocument(params[0].id)
).subscribe();

const saveDocument$ = params$.switchMap(
    params => this.saveDocument(params[0].id)
).subscribe();
```

then they work too. Help me understand why it's going on and how to force to work all sources in race, merge, etc.

Comment: they are cold observables. They start emitting when they are subscribed to (hence they are cold). For more info https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Get all of them to work or you want the first one done to work?

Comment: `race` does not subscribe to `openDocument$` or `saveDocument$` because `setTitle$` synchronously emits upon subscription.

Comment: I want setTitle to emit and then one of open or save document have to emit. how can i make setTitle work async in this situation?

Comment: The article from https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html#caveat-http-with-observables really helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with shared params source.

```
const params$ = this.route.params.map(
        routeParams => {

            return {
                id: <string>routeParams['id']
            };

        }
    ).combineLatest(
        this.config.getConfig()
    ).share();
```

I have shared it with share operator. But in this article from the first comment to my question i found this:

> When using multiple async pipes on streams with default values, the `.share()` operator might cause problems:
>
> The `share()` will publish the first value of the stream on the first subscription. The first async pipe will trigger that subscription and get that initial value. The second async pipe however will subscribe after that value has already been emitted and therefore miss that value.
>
> The solution for this problem is the `.shareReplay(1)` operator, which will keep track of the previous value of the stream. That way all the async pipes will get the last value.

I replaced `share()` with `shareReplay(1)` and all sources began emitting values.

```
const params$ = this.route.params.map(
        routeParams => {

            return {
                id: <string>routeParams['id']
            };

        }
    ).combineLatest(
        this.config.getConfig()
    ).shareReplay(1);
```

Thanks to everyone for help!

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/race.html?q=), the `.race()` operator does this:

> The observable to emit **first** is used.

That is why, you will only get **ONE** emission, because only one out of the three observables that emits first will get emitted.

What you are looking for is `.forkJoin()` or `.combineLatest()`.

If you want all the observables to execute in parallel and wait for ALL of them to come back as one observables, use `.forkJoin()`:

```js
Observable
    .forkJoin([...setTitle$, openDocument$, saveDocument$])
    .subscribe(([setTitle, openDocument, saveDocument]) => {
        //do something with your your results.
        //all three observables must be completed. If any of it was not completed, the other 2 observables will wait for it
    })
```

If you however wants to listen to every emission of all the observables regardless when they are emitted, use `.combineLatest()`:

```js
Observable
    .combineLatest(setTitle$, openDocument$, saveDocument$)
    .subscribe(([setTitle, openDocument, saveDocument]) => {
        //do something with your your results.
        // as long as any of the observables completed, it will be emitted here.
    });
```

Comment: "only one out of the three observables that completes first" should be "emits first".

Comment: I tried to use another operators like merge, concat, forkJoin, etc. No matter what operators i used, only the first source played. I found answer to this and posted bellow